# iptables is ignoring rules?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I've found some strange traffic through `tcpdump` (traffic is ongoing always):

```
13:00:13.203754 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 188.113.188.16.56881: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.204396 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 180.183.209.27.29546: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.204972 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 95.188.250.39.6881: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.205509 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 125.39.30.33.5493: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.206048 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 46.194.14.254.32232: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.206526 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 151.52.30.111.6881: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.207097 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 70.27.63.150.64389: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.207555 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 108.12.215.184.42880: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.208082 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 37.105.27.136.54752: UDP, length 103
13:00:13.209671 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 61.53.14.223.6881: UDP, length 106
13:00:13.266142 IP 46.35.235.75.10995 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.276353 IP 86.162.78.254.20206 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.345021 IP 108.12.215.184.42880 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.349955 IP 46.194.14.254.32232 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.357145 IP 70.27.63.150.64389 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.373275 IP 37.105.27.136.54752 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:13.785877 IP 61.53.14.223.6881 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 311
13:00:13.880421 IP 1.2.3.4.1028 > 86.38.202.92.63287: UDP, length 1438
13:00:13.913168 IP 122.174.79.84.34858 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 289
13:00:14.057212 IP 86.38.202.92.63287 > 1.2.3.4.1028: UDP, length 20
... many more lines with same or different hosts
```

1.2.3.4 is my WAN address (changed it to not make it very publicly available). Port 1028 is never opened in my firewall, I even tried to DROP it:

```
$IPT -I INPUT -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -I FORWARD -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -I FORWARD -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP

$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1028 -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1028 -j DROP
```

Rules look like this:

```
root@server-14:/# iptables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 67,68
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:221 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 state ESTABLISHED
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1028
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1028
```

`lsof -p 1028` doesn't show anything, `netstat -antlpu` doesn't show it either.

Tried with `-A`, with `-I`, even (as you can see) with both of them. It just doesn't work, traffic continues to flow. Sometimes at such rates that internet connection is becoming wobbly. I'm even starting to think that I've been put into some sort of botnet or something...

Answer (score 1):

`lsof -p 1028` filters for process ID `1028`.

You should try:

```
# lsof -Pnl +M -i4
```

for a list of open IPv4 ports and their owning processes. The `-Pnl` is optional, but makes it slightly quicker as it doesn't do name lookups etc for you.

Or:

```
# lsof -i :1028
```

to list everything listening on port 1028.

If there is something strange going on, then you need to get to the bottom of it instead of simply blocking the traffic with `iptables` rules.

Answer (score 1):

`tcpdump` shows you what the interface sees. Obviously packets have to arrive at the interface first before Netfilter (`iptables`) can kill them. Thus `iptables` can never prevent you from seeing incoming traffic. It can just prevent this traffic from having an effect (besides wasting your bandwidth...).

But there should not be any outgoing packets any more.

Maybe your Firewall is restarted from time to time?

Before I saw your rule set I thought that the problem is that the connections are already established. But your `DROP` rules are earlier. In general it may help to flush the known connections after making changes to the firewall: `conntrack flush`